# Blockscout backend docker crashing on ubuntu20.x

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I’m trying to deploy **BLOCKSCOUT** using the docker-compose following the steps mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.blockscout.com/for-developers/deployment/docker-compose-deployment).
But after deployment, my **backend docker starts crashing** and due to it the frontend fails to load any data to the dashboard.

Below I have shared my infra details:

```
Cloud: Google
Machine type: e2-standard-8
vCPU; 8
Mem: 32GB
CPU platform: Intel Broadwell
Architecture: x86/64

OS NAME="Ubuntu"
OS VERSION="20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
Docker version 25.0.1, build 29cf629
Docker Compose version v2.22.0
```

I have also tried using different versions of blockscout **(v6.2.2-beta, v6.2.1-beta, v6.2.0-beta)** and all are failing with similar error.
Following is the error that I’m getting from the backend docker:

```
warning: redefining module ConfigHelper (current version defined in memory)
backend          |   config/config_helper.exs:1
backend          | 
backend          | warning: redefining module ConfigHelper (current version defined in memory)
backend          |   config/config_helper.exs:1
backend          | 
backend          | Starting dependencies..
backend          | Starting repos..
backend          | Create Explorer.Repo database if it doesn't exist
backend          | Create Explorer.Repo.Account database if it doesn't exist
backend          | Create Explorer.Repo.BridgedTokens database if it doesn't exist
backend          | Running migrations for explorer
backend          | Running migrations for explorer
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:09.957Z","severity":"info","message":"Migrations already up","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:09.961Z","severity":"info","message":"Migrations already up","metadata":{}}
backend          | Running migrations for explorer
backend          | Success!
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:09.963Z","severity":"info","message":"Migrations already up","metadata":{}}
backend          | warning: redefining module ConfigHelper (current version defined in memory)
backend          |   config/config_helper.exs:1
backend          | 
backend          | warning: redefining module ConfigHelper (current version defined in memory)
backend          |   config/config_helper.exs:1
backend          | 
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.856Z","severity":"info","message":"[Que] Booting Que","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.856Z","severity":"info","message":"[Que] Booting Server Supervisor for Workers","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.878Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: collect records for txs per day stats","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.878Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: earliest date 2024-02-24 00:00:00Z","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.878Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: latest date 2024-02-24 23:59:59Z","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.918Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: timestamp cannot be converted to min/max blocks, trying to find min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.929Z","severity":"warn","message":"tx/per day chart: failed to get min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.929Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: collect records for txs per day stats","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.929Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: earliest date 2024-02-27 00:00:00Z","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.929Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: latest date 2024-02-27 23:59:59Z","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.930Z","severity":"info","message":"Running BlockScoutWeb.Endpoint with cowboy 2.10.0 at 0.0.0.0:4000 (http)","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.931Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: timestamp cannot be converted to min/max blocks, trying to find min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.933Z","severity":"warn","message":"tx/per day chart: failed to get min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.933Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: collect records for txs per day stats","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.933Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: earliest date 2024-02-28 00:00:00Z","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.933Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: latest date 2024-02-28 23:59:59Z","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.933Z","severity":"info","message":"Access BlockScoutWeb.Endpoint at ://:4000","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.935Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: timestamp cannot be converted to min/max blocks, trying to find min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.940Z","severity":"warn","message":"tx/per day chart: failed to get min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.940Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: collect records for txs per day stats","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.940Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: earliest date 2024-02-29 00:00:00Z","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.940Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: latest date 2024-02-29 23:59:59Z","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.944Z","severity":"info","message":"Index already caught up.","metadata":{"fetcher":"block_catchup","first_block_number":null,"last_block_number":null,"missing_block_count":0,"shrunk":false}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.944Z","severity":"info","message":"Checking if index needs to catch up in 5000ms.","metadata":{"fetcher":"block_catchup"}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.947Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: timestamp cannot be converted to min/max blocks, trying to find min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.956Z","severity":"warn","message":"tx/per day chart: failed to get min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.956Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: collect records for txs per day stats","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.956Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: earliest date 2024-03-02 00:00:00Z","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.956Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: latest date 2024-03-02 23:59:59Z","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.961Z","severity":"info","message":"Index already caught up.","metadata":{"fetcher":"block_catchup","first_block_number":null,"last_block_number":null,"missing_block_count":0,"shrunk":false}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.961Z","severity":"info","message":"Checking if index needs to catch up in 5000ms.","metadata":{"fetcher":"block_catchup"}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.963Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: timestamp cannot be converted to min/max blocks, trying to find min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.968Z","severity":"warn","message":"tx/per day chart: failed to get min/max blocks through a fallback option}","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.968Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: collect records for txs per day stats","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.968Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: records collected [%{date: ~D[2024-03-03], gas_used: 0, number_of_transactions: 0, total_fee: 0}, %{date: ~D[2024-03-02], gas_used: 0, number_of_transactions: 0, total_fee: 0}, %{date: ~D[2024-03-01], gas_used: 0, number_of_transactions: 0, total_fee: 0}, %{date: ~D[2024-02-29], gas_used: 0, number_of_transactions: 0, total_fee: 0}, %{date: ~D[2024-02-28], gas_used: 0, number_of_transactions: 0, total_fee: 0}, %{date: ~D[2024-02-27], gas_used: 0, number_of_transactions: 0, total_fee: 0}, %{date: ~D[2024-02-26], gas_used: 0, number_of_transactions: 0, total_fee: 0}, %{date: ~D[2024-02-25], gas_used: 0, number_of_transactions: 0, total_fee: 0}, %{date: ~D[2024-02-24], gas_used: 0, number_of_transactions: 0, total_fee: 0}]","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.968Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: save records","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.970Z","severity":"info","message":"tx/per day chart: number of inserted 10","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.977Z","severity":"info","message":"Index already caught up.","metadata":{"fetcher":"block_catchup","first_block_number":null,"last_block_number":null,"missing_block_count":0,"shrunk":false}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.977Z","severity":"info","message":"Checking if index needs to catch up in 5000ms.","metadata":{"fetcher":"block_catchup"}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.992Z","severity":"info","message":"Index already caught up.","metadata":{"fetcher":"block_catchup","first_block_number":null,"last_block_number":null,"missing_block_count":0,"shrunk":false}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:10.992Z","severity":"info","message":"Checking if index needs to catch up in 5000ms.","metadata":{"fetcher":"block_catchup"}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:11.002Z","severity":"info","message":"Application indexer exited: shutdown","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:11.008Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4290.0>) missed message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.4638.0>, :shutdown}","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:11.008Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4251.0>) missed message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.4638.0>, :shutdown}","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:11.008Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4288.0>) missed message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.4638.0>, :shutdown}","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"time":"2024-03-04T04:26:11.008Z","severity":"info","message":"Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.4297.0>) missed message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.4638.0>, :shutdown}","metadata":{}}
backend          | {"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_terminated,indexer,shutdown}"}
backend          | Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_terminated,indexer,shutdown})
backend          | 
backend          | Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Akhil

Comment: Can you please include a [mcve] inline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got fixed by following the steps:

In the blockscout/docker-compose/docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  backend:
    environment:
      ETHEREUM_JSONRPC_HTTP_URL: http://myrpc-url
      ETHEREUM_JSONRPC_TRACE_URL: http://myrpc-url
      # ETHEREUM_JSONRPC_WS_URL: ws://myrpc-url <<== Comment/remove this line
      CHAIN_ID: '2120'
```

In blockscout/docker-compose/envs/common-blockscout.env add or update the following line:

```
# Since my L2 is Polygon CDK
INDEXER_INTERNAL_TRANSACTIONS_TRACER_TYPE=polygon
```

Discussion related to it can be found here: https://discord.com/channels/973915550965174292/1214450097471885342

Thanks,

Akhil